# Need a list of week days with their number on iphone os

Tags: iphone, calendar, dayofweek

I'm working on a project that needs to have a list of weekdays.

I could get their locale names using the NSDateFormatter without a problem, but I was hoping to have an integer weekday also to save on the database and do some work.

Where can i get that number?

Thanks,
Leonardo

Comment: can you clarify a bit? are you looking to get the weekday from an NSDate?

Comment: No, i need the list of weeekdays (Mon, Thu, ...) which its corresponding weekday number (2,3,4,5) ... because I want to save those numbers in the database. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Apple Developers thread on NSDateComponents and weekday](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1700102)

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents =
        [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:dateOfInterest];

NSInteger weekday = [weekdayComponents weekday];
// weekday 1 = Sunday for Gregorian calendar

[gregorian release];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to get the numerical weekday from an `NSDate` object, you need to use `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents` like this:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
int weekday = [weekdayComponents weekday];
```